# How do I undo wx.grid.Grid.SetColAttr?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a grid application where a column can be, for instance, flagged as super-important. When this is done, I use `Grid.SetColAttr` to change the colour of the column. When the user removes the flag, however, I can't seem to undo the `SetColAttr`. Calling it again with `None` instead of an attribute object causes Python to mysteriously crash with no error message, and iterating over all the cells and calling `SetAttr(row, col, None)` has no effect on the color of the column. I guess that's because the column attribute overrides cell attributes when they are `None`.

So how do I undo the cell attribute change? I assume I'll have to call `SetColAttr` with the "default" grid attribute, but I don't even know if the grid has a default cell attribute or how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `SetColAttr` and `SetRowAttr` only. `SetAttr(row,col,None)` works (to reset individual cell). However, since these attributes are stored in different lists (cell/row/col), `SetAttr()` has no effect on column or row attributes.

Internally, `wxGridTableBase::SetColAttr()` attempts to assign the kind of the attribute 
([`wxGridCellAttr::SetKind()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_cell_attr.html#acc28e22664b1e4d390448c556993c440))
to the parameter provided. In case of `None`, it tries to call a method on a None object (actually a null pointer) which results in a crash.

You can bypass that assignment by calling `SetColAttr()` directly on the `wxGridCellAttrProvider` (this will also bypass a check for a valid GridCellAttrProvider and won't clear the attribute cache):

```
self.grid.GetTable().GetAttrProvider().SetColAttr(None,column)
```

This may leave a trace in the attribute cache, resulting in a cell not being reset. To clear the cache, call `SetAttr()`:

```
self.grid.SetAttr(-1,-1,None) # use invalid coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get default cell background color and text color and font (GetDefaultCellFont, GetDefaultCellBackgroundColour, etc) and set it based on that. I can't find anything to get a column's default attr though. Maybe by grabbing the cell's defaults, you can use them to set the column's.

I also found this neat answer that's sort of related and may help you figure it out:

[Fade in/out the background color of wxpython grid cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985305/fade-in-out-the-background-color-of-wxpython-grid-cell)

You should also read the wxGrid wiki page on the wxPython wiki: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGrid